# Converting an application from ESP32 board to STM32 board

Tags: arduino, stm32, esp32, eeprom

I wrote an app for my ESP32 but then I learned that ESP32 doesn't work well on batteries, since they got drained pretty quickly.

So I bought a STM-32 board (NUCLEO-32, STM32L432KC MCU): [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B077GFHLFS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077GFHLFS)
And I'm trying to implement the same application on that board.

Now, there are some things that worked on ESP32 but obviously doesn't work (or work differently) on the STM32 board.
BTW, I'm using the arduino IDE to write it to the STM32 as well.

The one that got me stuck for the last few hours was the EEPROM usage. I've been using it to keep some values in between restarts and sleep modes, but it seems like there's a different way to get it done on STM32 since EEPROM doesn't work there.
Tried to look up online for an answer, but couldn't find anything that I could understand (I'm a beginner).

Any chance anyone here knows what can I use here and how to use it, in order to keep values in between resets and standby/sleep modes?

This is the function I used for my esp32 app, to write to the EEPROM:

```
void writeToStorage(int addrOffset, const String &strToWrite)
{
  byte len = strToWrite.length();
  EEPROM.write(addrOffset, len);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    EEPROM.write(addrOffset + 1 + i, strToWrite[i]);
  }
  EEPROM.commit();
}
```

And this one was used to read from the EEPROM:

```
String readFromStorage(int addrOffset)
{
  int newStrLen = EEPROM.read(addrOffset);
  char data[newStrLen + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i < newStrLen; i++)
  {
    data[i] = EEPROM.read(addrOffset + 1 + i);
  }
  data[newStrLen] = '\0';
  return String(data);
}
```

So none of them works when trying to write to STM32... what should I replace it with to get the exact same results, but on STM32?

Comment: I'll be honest, I haven't looked deeply into this. (I'm curious too.) So all I can offer is that the ESP and STM32 processors are very different.  And that the real STM32 SDK from STMicro is very complex. That said, someone is porting the Arduino SDK to this STMicro board and may have not gotten around to supporting Non Volatile Memory. I would try and find if that effort (porting Arduino to the STM32) is online somewhere. I'd try github.com first. Then ask your question there in the form of a trouble-ticket / feature-request.

Comment: Actually, this github project and this particular trouble-ticket sounds like it may be of interest to you: https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/issues/1500

Comment: The STM32L432KC MCU doesn't have any internal EEPROM, and the NUCLEO-L432KC
doesn't have an external EEPROM. So if you want *simulated* EEPROM functionality you'll need to write some code or use a library which provides that for you by using some of the MCU's internal Flash.

Comment: Thank you @st2000!

Comment: @brhans do you know any existing library that might serve that purpose?